# To display value of the interface of type array[]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am displaying  api data in an component .The component looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div  *ngFor="let  customer of customers">
   <p>Name: {{customer?.name}}</p
   <p>Phone: {{customer?.phoneNumbers}}</p
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component,  Input } from '@angular/core';
import {  Customer } from '../models';

 @Component({
   selector: 'yn-contact',
    templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  })

 export class ContactComponent  {
     @Input()
     public customers: Customer ;
   }
```

Declared an interface called `Customer` in an `models.ts` file like this:

**models.ts** file

```
  export interface Customer {
     name: string;
     phoneNumbers: PhoneNumber[];
  }

  export interface PhoneNumber{
    type: string;
    displayName: string;
    number: string;
  }
```

Now in the **HTML**  i am able to display the `name`, But while displaying `phone` (i,e phone number), I am getting o/p like this:

[image]

**JSON:**

```
  { 
    "salutation": "Dr",
    "jobTitle": "Nurse Practicioner",
    "name": "Adaline Danat",
    "birthDate": "1964-06-04T06:31:10Z",
    "gender": "Female",


   "phoneNumbers": [
       {
        "type": "Unknown",
        "displayName": "Mobile",
        "number": "+62 342 886 8201"
      },
      {
        "type": "Other",
        "displayName": "Home",
        "number": "+86 707 128 1882"
      },
      {
        "type": "Business",
        "displayName": "Home",
        "number": "+63 704 441 1937"
      },
    ],

   }
```

Comment: How do you map your Json from the API to your interface ? The attributes don't even match (phone vs phoneNumbers)...

Comment: Sorry posted the  wrong interface code.

Comment: Please check the edited **CODE**.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
     <p>Name: {{customer?.name}}</p>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let phn of customer?.phone">
         <p>Phone: {{phn.number}}</p>
        </ng-container>
   </div>
```

Just use inner loop to display numbers, if you want display other info , you can do {{phn.displayName}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use key `(number)` of phone object, like this -

```
{{customer?.phone[0]?.number}}
```

PS: For debugging purpose in view side you can use `json` pipe in html like this -

```
{{customer?.phone | json}}
```

Comment: @Shankarguru what does it contains `{{customer?.phone | json}}`? have you checked

Comment: It is displying like this:  [ { "type": "Business", "displayName": "Mobile", "number": "+86 802 190 4343" } ]

Comment: can you share your JSON? `Customer` object

Comment: Okay let me share in the question.

Comment: @Shankarguru please check my updated answer, you need to use `{{customer?.phone[0]?.number}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184752/discussion-between-shankar-guru-and-pardeep-jain).

Comment: Please see the updated code(i,e interface). @Pardeep Jain